# HARA preferences details

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, finance, preferences

I am searching for some exntensive details about HARA preferences.  Where could I find some extensive details for HARA preferences? Something like a textbook or notes

Comment: Please narrow your question down to a scope that is suitable for the SE platform.

Comment: A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=HARA+preferences&oq=HARA+preferences) turns up many relevant results. Of course you can go straight to [Merton (1971)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002205317190038X) where properties and implications of HARA utility functions are first explored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper [Optimum consumption and portfolio rules in a continuous-time model (Merton (1971))](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002205317190038X) presents (as far as I know, the initial presentation.

[[image: Description of HAARA utility in Merton 19713]

Next we turn to a paper that discusses the importance of the HARA utility.
[The Fundamental Nature of HARA Utility (Perets and Yashiv (2013))](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Eyashiv/Sep2013.pdf)

> Many models in Economics assume a utility function belonging to the
> HARA family. This paper shows that HARA utility is fundamental to
> economic analysis. The HARA functional form is the unique form which
> satisfies basic economic principles in an optimization context. Using
> HARA is not just a matter of convenience or tractability but rather an
> essential restriction....

This notable paper has a multi page exploration of the HARA utility family.
[Implications of Constant Risk Aversion (Bamberg and Spremann (1981))](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01917173.pdf)

> The assumption of constant risk aversion often leads to a considerable
> simplification of decision theoretic analyses. It is shown that this
> restriction on constant risk aversion permits the description of a
> wide range of risk averse patterns between the extreme cases of risk
> neutrality and the exclusive orientation on the pessimistic maxmin
> criterion. In particular, a new axiomatic foundation of the constant
> risk aversion is given and a series of properties for the certainty
> equivalent are derived. Possible applications are shown by the
> treatment of risk premiums, values of information, portfolio
> selection, capital market theory and syndicates.

There is a book that I can't vouch for but may be useful:
[Hyperbolic absolute risk aversion: Second Edition](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hyperbolic-absolute-risk-aversion-Second/dp/1719230854)